# Scroll to end of messages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I've built a messenger system using view. The newest messages start bottom up. When you click on a conversation you'd like to view I'd like to automatically scroll to the bottom of the conversation after all of the messages have been loaded by axios.

**Conversation Messages Component**

```
methods: {
  getOldMessages(conversation_id){

        setTimeout(function() {
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: this.url,
        }).then(function(response) {
            //console.log(response.data);

            this.messages = response.data;

            this.scrollToEnd();

        }.bind(this))
        .catch(function(error) {

        });
    }.bind(this))
  },
  scrollToEnd: function() {     
    var container = this.$el.querySelector(".single-conversation");
    container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
  },
}
```

[Codepen example.](https://codepen.io/Corbin/pen/vVyeyZ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to scroll to the end of the messages view before `messages` has been rendered. You should wait until the [next tick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick) before scrolling:

```
this.messages = response.data;
this.$nextTick(() => this.scrollToEnd())
```

[your codepen with required changes](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/MPvByB?editors=1010)